# Extract the words that start with a vowel from a list input _list=[wood,old, apple,big,item, euphoria] using list comprehensions

Tags: python

Extract the words that start with a vowel from a

`list input _list=[wood,old, apple,big,item, euphoria]`

using list comprehensions.

```
Old
apple
item
euphoria
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
['old','apple','item','euphoria']
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. See [ask]

Comment: Complete this at home `[i[0].lower() in [] for i in input_list]` Somewhat like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track recognizing using that a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is appropriate for this task, consider trying the following:

```
>>> input_list = ['wood', 'old', 'apple', 'big', 'item', 'euphoria']
>>> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
>>> output_list = [word for word in input_list if word and word[0].lower() in vowels]
>>> output_list
['old', 'apple', 'item', 'euphoria']
```

As an aside, since python employs [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) using [Hungarian naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for variables in Python is kinda [sus](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sus) [ngl](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ngl)...

Answer (score 0):

- import ast,sys
- input_str = sys.stdin.read()
- input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
- list_vowel = [input_str for input_str in input_list if input_str and input_str[0].lower() in "aeiou"]
- print(list_vowel)